# Hardhat: how to deploy using a custom signer

Tags: deployment, ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat

Normally, to deploy contracts to a network, we specify the private keys in `accounts` section of the network config, Like below, and these accounts get used in signing the transactions.

```js
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "rinkeby",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    rinkeby: {
      url: "https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/1234",
      accounts: [privateKey1, privateKey2, ...]
    }
  },
```

**But** we need to use a **custom signer** that will sign the transactions instead. All transactions that are part of the deployment process needs to be signed via this custom signer.

How do I do this using Hardhat/ethers.js ?

Comment: could you elaborate more on wdym by custom signer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the deployment script to attach your custom signer to the contract factory (https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-contract.html):

```js
async function main() {
    const HelloBar = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloBar");
    const signer = createYourCustomSigner();

    // attach the signer to the factory
    HelloBar = HelloBar.connect(signer);

    const hellobar = await HelloBar.deploy();

    await hellobar.deployed();

    console.log("Address:", hellobar.address);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Then run the script with:

```bash
npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/deploy.js
```